# 200k Handles in TaskManager: Server out of memory / How to get list of used ressources

Tags: windows, winapi, smtp, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server 2003 Small Business System here. The problem: there are about 200.000 handles which are consuming almost all the memory of the machine and I don't know how to determine which of the services is using all that memory and why.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to get to that information. Maybe via batch-script?

On the server runs:

- SQL-Server
- Windows Exchange
- Trend Micro
- Acronis

Any help would be great. Let me know if you need further information.

---

**UPDATE:**

I recognized that the problem is the SMTP server that gets a sh*tload of mail.
It seems that someone/something uses my relay to send spam mails. Does anyone know how I can prevent thit?

Comment: Try SuperUser or ServerFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try two utilities from sysinternals suite (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) - either cmd line `handle` or more versatile `Process Explorer`.

Note: You'd have to open/display lower pane on `PE` to view handles.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me getting to the cause. It seems to be the SMTP server.

Comment: @Stefan, it looks like you forgot to mark this as your answer.

Comment: Oh sorry thought I did. Thanks for the hint.